# Batch script to copy lines from one text file to another base on ID

Tags: batch-file

I need to write a batch script to copy those lines from a pipe-delimited file that have one of two given ID numbers.

For example, for this file:

```
Jack | 12 | Jacksonville
Jane | 34 | Minneapolis
```

The ID numbers that have to be hardcoded are 12 and 56.
So a new text file has to be generated will contain this:

```
Jack | 12 | Jacksonville
```

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All ID's matching either 12 or 56 in the file `IDFile.txt` will be outputted into a new file `MatchingIDs.txt`.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set line=0
for /f "tokens=2 delims=|" %%a in (IDFile.txt) do (
set num=%%a
set num=!num: =!
if !num!==12 set bool=true
if !num!==56 set bool=true
if "!bool!"=="true" call :GETLINE
set /a line+=1
set bool=false
)

:GETLINE
if not %line%==0 set skip=skip=%line%
for /f "%skip% tokens=* delims=" %%b in (IDFile.txt) do (
echo %%b >>MatchingIDs.txt
goto :BREAK
)
:BREAK
```

Comment: Didn't work.. Are you sure  `set num=!num: =!` and `set skip=skip=%line%` are syntactically correct? (Apologies, very new to batch scripting)

Comment: @Shalapolia It worked fine for me, try adding a `pause` above the `:GETLINE` and see if it gives you any errors. Yes :) the first removes the spaces from `!num!` as there are spaces separating the pipes, and the second sets the skip variable for the `for` loop if the value to skip is more than 0, if it's not then it won't be defined so it won't be run, because `skip=0` is not syntactically correct.

Comment: Ah, its kinda working now. Thanks Bali! Just one more question: It works when I hardcode 2-digit ID numbers but not when I use 7-digit ones. Where is that declared exactly?

Comment: Ah, my bad. Just had to change the number of tokens. Many thanks Bali! :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you mean by "copy". I'm assuming you want to create a new file containing just the matching lines. There is a very simple solution using FINDSTR with regular expressions. Each regex looks for the ID in the 2nd column, and allows any number of spaces (including 0) before and after the ID.

```
findstr /rb /c:"[^|]*| *12 *|" /c:"[^|]*| *56 *|" "file.txt" >"newFile.txt"
```

**Update: 2015-12-20**

FINDSTR has very primitive and totally non-standard regex support. Lack of alternation forces each number alternative to require the entire regex. This can be a problem if you are searching for many more alternatives.

There is a much simpler solution using my [JREPL.BAT regex text processing tool](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6044). It is pure script (hyrid JScript/batch) that runs natively on any Windows machine from XP onward.

```
call jrepl "^[^|]*\| *(12|56) *\|.*" $0 /jmatch /f "test.txt" /o "newFile.txt"
```

It is a simple matter to add additional pipe delimited numbers to search for within the parentheses.